# Usage of the word “issue”

Tags: single-word-requests

I consider the word *issue* to be a loose synonym of the word *problem*. Can I use the word *issue* to refer to the scope of problems discussed in some work of art? For example, *the opera's issue*? By the way, can I call an opera *work of art* or this term can be applied only to pictures, scuptures and stuff like that?

Comment: Some more context in how you would use it would help. Do you mean to use _The opera's issue ..._ to say _The only problem with the opera was ..._ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Opera's issue* does not sound correct to me, but so does *opera's problem*. You could say, however:

> The problem of segregation is raised in this work.
>
> The issue of racism was addressed in this play.

As for opera being a [work of art](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_of_art), I don't see a problem with that, but *work of art* is usually referred to a physical object. Still:

> Used more broadly, the term [work of art] is less commonly applied to:
>
> - A fine work of architecture or landscape design
> - A production of live performance, such as theater, ballet, opera, performance art, musical concert and other performing arts, and other
>     ephemeral, non-tangible creations.

Comment: Vilmar, thank you very much for this full answer! The only difficulty is that I want to refer to the scope of problems, discussed in the opera, while the phrase "the scope of problems, discussed in the opera" is too long for a header. But if I say “On the opera's problem” if would mean that there is only one problem discussed in the opera, am I wrong?

Comment: To me when I see "the opera's problem", I would first think that there was a problem with the opera (e.g. the actors performed poorly). Though that is only my opinion :)

Comment: Well, hah, how would you express my thought than?

Comment: I would stick with your initial phrase, you could omit "scope of" to shorten the phrase: "the problems/issues discussed/raised/addressed in the opera..."